# Adding Numerical Suffixes to Tag-Names to Distinguish XML Elements

Tags: sed, xml

I have an XML file with multiple child elements which have the same tag-name, ex. `<Name>Luigi</Name>`, `<Name>Mario</Name>`, `<Name>Peach</Name>`. Here is a mock-up of what my input file looks like:

```
<!-- names.xml -->
<Names>
    <Name>Luigi</Name>
    <Name>Mario</Name>
    <Name>Peach</Name>
</Names>
```

When I throw this file into Excel for analysis it creates a new record for each `Name` element. This is awesome from a readability perspective, but it makes it difficult to discern if I have lots of duplicate data outside of the name fields.

What I want to do is rename the tags to `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3` so that they all appear on the same row when I import them into Excel. That way I'll be able to find records that are useless to me or that contain duplicates - without having to constantly look at the raw data.

In other words, I want a script or command which produces the following output:

```
<!-- names.xml -->
<Names>
    <Name1>Luigi</Name1>
    <Name2>Mario</Name2>
    <Name3>Peach</Name3>
</Names>
```

Is it possible to do this with a **sed** command or other Unix script?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want your output to be. Can you give a small example input file and example output file?

Comment: I'd like my output to be: `<Name>Luigi</Name>`, `<Name1>Mario</Name1>`, `<Name2>Peach</Name2>`

Comment: Please provide a segment of your XML file, including parent elements. (Make up the data values if you like.) That will give tools like `xmlstarlet` something to grip on to. Remember to put it in your question, not here in the comments.

Comment: I made a guess as to what you're looking for and posted a solution. Let me know if it looks like it's doing the right thing and I'll add some explanation.

Comment: In general what you're asking for is bad practice. XML that uses composite element names like this will be much more difficult to process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you specifically asked for `sed`, here is a `sed`/`bash` script that should do what you want, provided that each `<Name>` element is opened and closed on the same line:

```bsh
(IFS='';
n=0;
while read line; do
    if echo "${line}" | grep -Pq "<Name>\w+</Name>"; then
        ((n++));
        echo "${line}" | sed "s/<Name>\(\w\+\)<\/Name>/<Name${n}>\1<\/Name${n}>/";
    else
        echo "${line}";
    fi;
done) < names.xml
```

I tested it with this input file:

```
<!-- names.xml -->
<Names>
    <Name>Luigi</Name>
    <Name>Mario</Name>
    <Name>Peach</Name>
</Names>
```

And it produced the following output:

```
<Names>
    <Name1>Luigi</Name1>
    <Name2>Mario</Name2>
    <Name3>Peach</Name3>
</Names>
```

That said, this seems like a good candidate for a language with an XML parsing library. Here is a Python script that does what you want:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- encoding: ascii -*-

# add_suffix.py

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree

# Load the data
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(sys.argv[1])
root = tree.getroot()

# Update the XML tree
suffix = 0
for name in root.iter("Name"):
    suffix += 1
    name.tag += str(suffix)

# Write out the updated data
tree.write(sys.argv[2])
```

Run it like this:

```bsh
python add_suffix.py names.xml new_names.xml
```

Comment: That output is exactly what I'm looking for!