# Rename XML elements to a sequence

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I was looking at a possible XML-based solution to [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403768/adding-numerical-suffixes-to-tag-names-to-distinguish-xml-elements). I'm aware of its [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403775/100397), which offers `sed` and `python` solutions.

The given XML fragment is:

```
<Names>
    <Name>Luigi</Name>
    <Name>Mario</Name>
    <Name>Peach</Name>
</Names>
```

and the requirement is to change the `<Name/>` element names to a sequence `<Name1/>`, `<Name2/>`, `<Name3/>`, etc.

Using `xmlstarlet` I can rename the `<Name/>` element values to an fixed value with something like this

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//Name' -v 'Another' names.xml

<Names>
  <Another>Luigi</Another>
  <Another>Mario</Another>
  <Another>Peach</Another>
</Names>
```

And I can even change the element values to an expression with `-x` (`--expr`).

But for editing element names themselves there is no `-x` (`--expr`) option as an alternative to the `-v` (`--value`) option, so I cannot use something like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//Name' -x 'concat(., position())' names.xml
```

Using an XML-aware tool such as `xmlstarlet`, is it possible to transform the input XML to differentiate the `<Name/>` elements like this, and if so, how?

```
<Names>
    <Name1>Luigi</Name1>
    <Name2>Mario</Name2>
    <Name3>Peach</Name3>
</Names>
```

Comment: This should be doable via XSLT, but not trivial.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I thought it might be possible with XSLT but I don't know enough about it to know where to begin. It just seems strange that to edit XML I should have to revert to a non-XML-aware tool such as `sed`!

Comment: You shouldn't have to. XSLT does have the ability to emit arbitrary tags, but you'll probably have to recurse templates in order to get the numbering.

Comment: This isn't anything specific to Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with XML command-line tools has left me with the feeling that there's a lot to be desired. Almost without fail I find myself giving up and just using Python. That said, I think I have an XQuery solution to this problem that works with the `basex` utility. Here is the XQuery expression:

```xml
<!-- xml_rename_sequence.xquery -->
for $name at $position in doc('names.xml')//Name
return rename node $name as concat(name($name),$position)
```

And here is the XML data file:

```
<!-- names.xml -->
<Names>
    <Name>Luigi</Name>
    <Name>Mario</Name>
    <Name>Peach</Name>
</Names>
```

Here is how we run the script (it modifies the file in-place):

```bsh
basex -u xml_rename_sequence.xquery
```

And here is the updated data file:

```
<!-- names.xml -->
<Names>
  <Name1>Luigi</Name1>
  <Name2>Mario</Name2>
  <Name3>Peach</Name3>
</Names>
```

I also tried using the following tools (without success):

- [xqilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/CommandLine)
- [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

Here were some posts I found regarding incrementing a counter in XQuery:

- [XQuery counters inside a for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652397/xquery-counters-inside-a-for)
- [Updating counter in XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294677/updating-counter-in-xquery)
- [xquery - how to increment a counter variable within a for loop/ how to convert array of string values into node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450767/xquery-how-to-increment-a-counter-variable-within-a-for-loop-how-to-convert-ar)

And here were some other references I used:

- [BaseX: XQuery Update](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update)
- [XQuery Update for the impatient](http://www.xmlmind.com/tutorials/XQueryUpdate/)
- [XQuery Update queries in BaseX are succesful, but no changes are written to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315293/xquery-update-queries-in-basex-are-succesful-but-no-changes-are-written-to-the)